# Owners manual has a different year than model year of car?

Tags: mercedes-benz

I have a Mercedes built in March of 2012 according to the door sticker. The VIN comes out as 2012 as well.

However the 2012 edition of the owners manual is not my model and has older features. The 2013 edition of the owners correctly describes my vehicle. So, what is going on with this? Why would the 2012 car be described in the "2013 edition" owner's manual?

Comment: When *exactly* was the car made? More than likely you have a MY 2013 which was made in 2012.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I told you all I know in the question: the door sticker says it was manufactured in March of 2012..

Comment: Is it a European import? What I mean is, was it manufactured and titled in Europe, then sent to the States?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 No..

Comment: Then call up MB and see what's going on. They'll have the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a car that was manufactured in 2012 but is actually the 2013 model year. That is more common than you might think: I purchased my car in April of 2003 but it is the 2004 model year. It has all sorts of different features, much like you describe with yours.